# Can I still romance Garrus?

Tags: mass-effect-2

For my second playtrough I've decided I want to romance Garrus. I did his loyalty mission already. We've had the talk about blowing off steam by sparring, where I accidently didn't take the flirty option. Garrus has been continuing his endless calibrations ever since.

I currently still have the

> Obtain the Reaper IFF

mission left, but I am saving it for later. Will completing it (Or any other mission) allow me to take another shot at romancing him, or did I screw up when I said that one wrong thing?

Comment: Have you looked through the other [romance questions](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=[mass-effect-2]+romance) yet?  There may be something there that you weren't aware of.

Comment: @MBraedley I have. There are no other questions about romancing Garrus, and those that do mention it are in the situation before the conversation I had with him.